# How to integrate Quill (rich-text-editor) with react-final-form?

Tags: quill, rich-text-editor, react-final-form, final-form

How to integrate [Quill (rich-text-editor)](https://quilljs.com/) with [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/react)?

Answer (score 0):

Thats it works for me

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { Field } from 'react-final-form';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

const FormQuill: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => (
  <Field name={name}>
    {({ input: { value, ...input } }) => (
      <ReactQuill
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue, delta, source) => {
          if (source === 'user') {
            input.onChange(newValue);
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
  </Field>
);

export default FormQuill;
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Great that you added an answer. Thus, would like to suggest a working demonstration, explanation of your answer (at a very least) helps the OP to understand why your answer stands out. Also good to know: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).